# I promised ALLAH not to masturbate at all but I broke my Promise. Can I ask Alah For a Second Chance?

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness

On first Ramadan i told my self to never masturbate. Around 3rd or 4 th day of Ramadan I made a promise to Allah before sleeping that I would never masturbate in my entire life again. At that time I was willing to make this promise. 16 days in Ramadan and after Iftar after 2 hours I broke my Promise. I did not want to break it but I got distracted to same nsfw stuff and just could not resist. I made a promise to Allah that if I ever broke my promise ten I would fast for 10 days and give money to the poor during these 10 days. As I broke my promise in Ramadan so I can still fast and now give money to the poor for 10 straight days. But I really did not want to break this promise. Everyhthing was going so good but today after iftar I just really wanted to masturbate.Now I am in deep guilt. I need to know Can I ask Allah to give me a second chance and I will not break my promise this time. Is this possible. Can I make a due in Isha to forgive me and let  me continue my promise of never masturbating again just forgive me once and I will never masturbate again. And if I ever break break my promise than I will Fast for a month and give money to the poor for the whole month. Can i Ask this to Allah in Isha prayer while making a dua from my heart and then never masturbate again. I am firm in my decesion of never masturbating ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allah says in Surah Al-Ma'idah (Verse 89):

> [...] "***for its expiation*** (a deliberate oath that is broken) ***feed ten Masakin*** (poor persons), ***on a scale of the average of that with which you feed your own families, or clothe them or manumit a slave. But whosoever cannot afford (that), then he should fast for three days. That is the expiation for the oaths when you have sworn. And protect your oaths*** (i.e. do not swear much)

You should not make oaths which you will likely break, especially concerning sins by promising to Allah that you will not do them again because we are all weak and will always sin (although your intention has to be to always avoid every sin and to never commit them).

You can make two intentions during Ramadan, that you will fast for Ramadan and in the same time expiate your sin that you have broken your oath.

Of course, you should definitely seek forgiveness from Allah for those two sins, and there are many ways of doing so.

The best is described in this hadith:

> Abu Bakr (rn) narrated: 'I heard the Apostle of Allah (ﷺ) saying': "*When a servant (of Allah) commits a sin, and he performs ablution well, and then stands and prays two Rak'at, and asks pardon of Allah, Allah pardons him.*" He then recited this verse **[Qur'an 3:135]**: "***And those who, when they commit indecency or wrong their souls, remember Allah***"  - End Quote of the Hadith - [...] ***and seek forgiveness for their sins - and who can forgive sins except Allah? And [who] do not persist in what they have done while they know.***" Narrated in Abu Dawud ([1521](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1521)) and Shaykh Albani classed it Sahih